# IMAP - ENVELOPE vs. RFC822 headers, Fetching whole message vs body parts, etc

Tags: imap

I'm writing an IMAP client and I have a question.

To get Sender, From, To, CC, etc -

I can FETCH RFC822.HEADER , which will give me a long string w/sometimes not relevant information, or I can FETCH ALL / FETCH ENVELOPE, which will give me a nice formatted version of the main info I need, which is Date, Subject, Sender, etc.

To get email message / attachments -

I can FETCH BODY.PEEK[], which will give me a MIME string with every part of the message regardless of whether I want it (nor does it give the MIME boundaries in an easy to read parse format like BODYSTRUCTURE does), or I can FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE / FETCH (BODY ENVELOPE), then parse out the individual parts I want/need, without having to download everything.

My question is whether using the rfc822 headers, or downloading an entire MIME string, is every really necessary in an email client? It seems like BODYSTRUCTURE & ENVELOPE have made this much easier, so is there any reason I would ever need to manually parse the RFC822 headers / MIME message in my email client? I should be able to do everything a client would ever need with ENVELOPE & BODYSTRUCTURE, correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make do with `BODYSTRUCTURE`, `ENVELOPE` (and `BODY.PEEK[1]` etc when you need to fetch bodyparts).

You may find that at some point, before or after 1.0, you may choose to e.g. retrieve `BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (List-Id)]` or other things. But overall you're right, `BODYSTRUCTURE` and `ENVELOPE` are enough.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll keep a feature where the end user can "view email headers" (then return the original RFC822 headers), like the Gmail webclient does, so you can see origin IP and all that, but I see no point in parsing it because it provides no information that my client would need to use to make important decisions with, and any important information is already given in BODYSTRUCTURE & ENVELEOPE. My guess is IMAP devs kept the old way of doing things for pop3 backwards compatability.

Comment: Also keep in mind servers do not always parse things the same way you would. Many practical client download a subset of the headers rather than rely on envelope.

Comment: Can you expand on that please Max? Please give examples of commands used to obtain information in subsets of headers that are not relied on in the envelope. I've not found anything to this effect.

Comment: @max at the stage where he is, parsing differences between servers is not likely to be on the top-50 list of concerns.

Comment: @pulga the first difference I ran across was that gmail and another server disagreed about which messages were part of the same thread.

Comment: You may be interested in headers that are not part of the envelope.  Good examples are Priority headers (for importance), In-Reply-To/References headers for proper threading, and reply building.  And once you're downloading some headers, you might as well get all your information from headers, imho.

Comment: FWIW, GMail's BODYSTRUCTURE responses break if the message contains a message/rfc822 part where the Content-Transfer-Encoding is base64 (and probably quoted-printable). This is supposed to be illegal and so should be rare, but I have run into it.

Comment: Contrary to what's been said parsing differences in servers is definitely on my top concerns, so please, feel free to mention any use case in which headers are necessary. However, @Max, the In-Reply-To value is the last value of the ENVELOPE in the result of FETCH (BODY ENVELOPE), so headers aren't required for that, and not sure about References, but I've built replies and shipped them off via SMTP w/out problems. Perhaps there are features specific to Gmail?

Comment: @jstedfast, I've parsed a lot of rfc822 BODYSTRUCTURES, and although the formatting is different I've never seen them break BODYSTRUCTURE, not on Gmail or any other server. Same thing goes for BODY. And I don't think there is anything illegal about base64 encoding rfc822 replies?

Comment: When GMail encounters a message/rfc822 part that is base64 encoded, it returns a LISP expression that syntactically is body-part-basic instead of body-part-message as you would expect when the first 2 tokens are "message" and "rfc822". And yes, base64 encoded message/rfc822 is illegal.

Comment: From rfc2045, section 6.4: Certain Content-Transfer-Encoding values may only be used on certain
   media types.  In particular, it is EXPRESSLY FORBIDDEN to use any
   encodings other than "7bit", "8bit", or "binary" with any composite
   media type, i.e. one that recursively includes other Content-Type
   fields.  Currently the only composite media types are "multipart" and
   "message".

Comment: The References header is not needed to create replies, but it is necessary for threading messages. You can sometimes get away with just the In-Reply-To header value, but that only gives you the direct parent. References provides the reply chain of message-id's which provides you with much more context for threading.

Comment: BTW, search https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/MailKit/Net/Imap/ImapUtils.cs#L809 for 'GMail' for some workarounds for the GMail IMAP implementation.

Comment: @jstedfast, well in all fairness, we've tested well over 10 diff. IMAP servers and never found a single one that is 100% legal, and I know of several other things Gmail does that is illegal but yes I know see what you mean. Thanks for the explanation on references, it now seems Reference is the only thing in the headers that is actually needed and I think your/Max's answer are the best ones.

Comment: However, I still think it's better to use BODYSTRUCTURE (I don't think your mail client lib does that as I saw people asking questions about how to get individual attachments instead of having to dl the whole message) for general message reading.

Comment: I personally think this is the best way to deal w/emails -  For example, a client could FETCH (BODY ENVELOPE), receiving all important  information about messages, then if necessary FETCH BODY[x], then if and only if the message warrants a reply go on to fetch the reference field via something like BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (References)]. No point in downloading what is not needed, especially for those w/limited bandwidth. In my humble opinion, fetching the entire headers to view core info and fetching entire messages to view just main html or plain text body is very wasteful.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a number of comments. But I'll add it it: The only way to learn about bodyparts without downloading the entire message is BODY(STRUCTURE). The BODY/BODYSTRUCTURE fetch item includes ENVELOPE for some messages, so parsing it requires an ENVELOPE parser. Once you have an ENVELOPE parser, why bother with an address field parser? What's the added value of having an address field parser if you already have an ENVELOPE parser?

Comment: @Pulga, My library allows you to use BODY/BODYSTRUCTURE or request the headers. It essentially is just a low-level C# API on top of the IMAP protocol that allows you to do just about everything you can do with IMAP.

Comment: I agree that using BODYSTRUCTURE and ENVELOPE is the way to go, at least as long as the IMAP server isn't completely broken or something. I think @max's point was that if you find yourself requesting ENVELOPE + a bunch of individual headers, it might be more efficient to just request the full message headers.

Comment: I meant a subset of headers that you're interested in, using header.fields, but otherwise yes.

Comment: @arnt, agreed, on rfc822 messages, when fetching BODY ENVELOPE you will get 2 envelopes. Pretty pointless. In general I think BODY/BODYSTRUCTURE is good but certain servers mess it up bad, like yahoo for example, has no idea what BODY is and will -always- send BODYSTRUCTURE.

Comment: Great discussion guys, if you can think of any real world use case for header values that aren't included in BODY/BODYSTRUCTURE/ENVELOPE please feel free to continue. Thanks to all participants.

Comment: The two envelopes you get refer to different data, e.g. the forwarded (inner) and forwarding (outer) messages. And there are many fields you might want, e.g. list-unsubscribe if your client has an unsubscription feature, references to thread, thread-index if you have a microsoft fetish (see http://rant.gulbrandsen.priv.no/aox/thread-index for more). There's a thousand features to add if you really want to, but IMO they're all in the "later, if at all" category.